# What does HRESULT 0x80070057 mean, and why is my program crashing?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010

I've written a program that takes two images, then runs an algorithm on them to isolate a hand in the "foreground" and match the gesture to a known one.

A few days ago, I ran the program with some test parameters, just to test a few tweaks I had made, and it all worked fine. I have not touched the code since then.

Today, I ran the program with two new images, and it crashed, giving me the error code `0x0` and `HRESULT=0x80070057`. Beyond this, when I stopped debugging from C# Visual Studio 2010 Express, somehow, the debugging stopped, according to studio. But the form is still up, unresponsive, and unable to be closed, even from Task Manager. I can't run the program, because it says another instance is still running.

What could be causing this? And what can I try to fix it? I'd be happy to provide any other details that might be helpful; I'm relatively inexperienced and don't really know what is and isn't helpful.

**Addition:** I stopped and started studio, and that seems to have fixed the problem. Still, if someone can explain what may have happened, it would be much appreciated.

**Another detail:** The program crashed near the end of what it was supposed to do. I was able to start, load both pictures, and run the algorithm, but in the last step, it crashed on me.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Could not load file or assembly ... The parameter is incorrect](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8269386/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-the-parameter-is-incorrect)

Comment: I don't think It's not a duplicate because this is not ASP.net related.

Comment: IIRC there are one or two error codes (HResults) that are relatively generic, and that is one of them - i.e. it cannot be traced to a specific error. (I used to strike that reasonably frequently back when doing WinAPI on VB6).

Comment: @rlbisbe: I googled for the code and it seems that it's asp.net related, maybe the poster wasn't tagging the thread correctly.

Comment: The only way the program uses ASP.net would be if that is included in the standard C#, Windows, or Microsoft Visual C# studio packages. I have never explicitly done something involving ASP. And after restarting Studio, I could run the same pictures which gave me a problem the first time, with no problem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Could not load file or assembly ... The parameter is incorrect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8269386/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-the-parameter-is-incorrect)

Answer (score 3):

From what I know the error code means, that an assembly couldn't be loaded.
It is corrupt or not avaliable.

Clear the `\bin` folder of your project and the AppData (Temp) folder (located at `C:\Users\your_username\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET`) and see if the error still happens.

<sup>Source [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/desktop/aa378137%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)</sup>

> **`E_INVALIDARG`:** One or more arguments are not valid (`0x80070057`)

Comment: This answer is a total copy of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8269386/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-the-parameter-is-incorrect/8269493#8269493

Answer (score 0):

You may be using an assembly that couldn't be loaded correctly. For checking which one may fail I would recommend you this utility: http://www.dependencywalker.com/

It scans your app for dependencies and highlight the ones that were not found. In my case was a C++ assembly that was missing.