# Visual Studio 2013 Error Message: 0x80004001 (E_NOTIMPL)

Tags: exception, visual-studio-2013, sql-server-2014, hresult

For some reason, Microsoft Visual Studio 2013 keeps giving me the following error:

> Not implemented (Exception from HRESULT: x080004001 (E_NOTIMPL))

[image: **Microsoft Visual Studio** - Not implemented (Exception from HRESULT: x080004001 (E_NOTIMPL)) and Add New Table Window]

[image: **Microsoft Visual Studio** - Not implemented (Exception from HRESULT: x080004001 (E_NOTIMPL))]

I receive this error when attempting to make a new SQL table. The way I reproduce this error is by doing the following:

1. Open my project (from Team Explorer)
2. Open the Data Connection in Server Explorer.
3. Right click on Tables and click Add New Table

I am attempting to add a new table to a SQL Server 2014 database. I have Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2013 Version 12.0.31101.00 Update 4

This only happens when Adding a table or opening the definition. I can view data without any errors. I have also tried repairing Visual Studio 2013 with no luck.

**EDIT:**
Now, When I don't open a project and try adding a table, I am getting:

> "The parameter is incorrect. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070057 (E_INVALIDARG))".

[image: **Microsoft Visual Studio** - The parameter is incorrect. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070057 (E_INVALIDARG))]

Comment: Can you add tables OK in SQL Server Management Studio?

Comment: I can add tables just fine through SQL Server Management Studio. I will try using a different Windows account when I get a chance.

Comment: I tried using a different Windows account and had the same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up formatting and re-installing Windows which fixed the problem when I installed Visual Studio 2013 again. Repairing Visual Studio did not fix the problem but I'm not sure if re-installing visual studio would have worked.

Answer (score 2):

Found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14871449/exception-from-hresult-0x80070057-e-invalidarg)

> Clear out the temporary framework files for your project in:
>
> For Windows 7, the path is:
>   C:\Users\[username]\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\
>
> For 64 bit systems with 'Framework' in the path the full path is:
>   C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\
>
> http://www.solutioncottage.com/ShowSolution.aspx?solID=59

Comment: Unfortunately this did not solve my problem. I tried clearing the AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files folder and both the Framework and Framework64 Temporary.... Files for all versions. The link you gave doesn't mention SQL (or the original error) and is for debugging applications with my second error as the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Usually `E_INVALIDARG` returns when there is an application level on with the parameter for example out of range issue or parameter that collide with each other.

As I found; [You may receive an `E_INVALIDARG` error message when you try to create an instance of a .NET serviced component](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/837522), You need to modify your *[Registry of Windows](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/256986)*.

> Make a new backup of your `Registry of Windows`.

**Source:** A Microsoft .NET serviced component that is deployed in the COM+ environment.
**Source event:** An activation request.
**Side event :** Destroying an old instance of the serviced component.
**Side sources :** All the other resources that are associated with the old serviced component.
**Causes :**

- This destruction may not be successful or
- COM+ may not clean up the associated resources.

**Resolution :** Downloading [the Microsoft .NET Framework 1.1 Service Pack 1](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=A8F5654F-088E-40B2-BBDB-A83353618B38).
**Registry Edits :**

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\COM3\System.EnterpriseServices]
"DisableAsyncFinalization"=dword:00000001
```

Comment: Faulting app name: devenv.exe, version: 12.0.31101.0, time: 0x54548724
Faulting module name: Microsoft.VisualStudio.Platform.WindowManagement.ni.dll, ver: 12.0.31101.0, time: 0x545487c9
Exception code: 0xc00000fd
Fault offset: 0x00093c94
Faulting process id: 0x958
Faulting app start time: 0x01d0805524a4398a
Faulting application path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\Microsoft.Vc38f2c7b#\81d24d910f66229e0b8bb4c791751b48\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Platform.WindowManagement.ni.dll

Comment: After doing this (minus downloading 1.1 because it wouldn't install saying the versions don't match), I've exchanged one error for another after doing the registry edit. I received the error in my comment above. I will award you points but I plan to do a complete reinstall of Windows at this point.