# Warning 1 The parameter is incorrect. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070057 (E_INVALIDARG)) 0 0

Tags: vb.net

[image]

I always encounter this problem when i importing pictures into picture boxes i created many new project but this appears always anyone please helppp

Comment: See: [Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070057 (E_INVALIDARG)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14871449/exception-from-hresult-0x80070057-e-invalidarg) Or [this](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/15434/cannot-find-wrapper-assembly-for-type-library-envd.html)

Comment: "Parameter is not valid" is a very generic error message.  Commonly generated by any GDI or GDI+ code, that's relevant to using images in a form design.  If you've been able to open the design window for this form before then it is not a problem with image format.  Next likely candidate is that VS ran out of memory.