# AjaxControlToolkit - Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070057 (E_INVALIDARG)

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012

Good afternoon guys,

I have a problem when compiling my application, NO is loading the AjaxControlToolkit. I'm using v3.5 of the AjaxControlToolkit. Visual studio 2012. Everything was working normally, my computer crashed and restarted alone, after the application did not work.

What I already tried:

- Perform 'Clean' and 'Build'.
- Remove the reference and reference it again.
- On the path C: \ Windows \ Microsoft.NET \ Framework \ v4.0.30319 \ Temporary ASP.NET Files, contains nothing to be deleted as the suggestions that I read.

Any help will be welcome, sorry if some information is missing.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that worked for me:

Clear both:

1. the \bin folder of your project
2. the temp folder (should be     C:\Users\your_username\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files in
   windows 7)

Same solution as in
"[Could not load file or assembly ... The parameter is incorrect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8269386/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-the-parameter-is-incorrect)".