# TestComplete Error "0x80070057 The parameter is incorrect." when executing ClickCell

Tags: automation, runtime-error, testcomplete, regression-testing

I'm experiencing a problem that I could not find a solution for yet.
I use Test Complete to automate some GUI related scenarios for an app. I developed some scripts that were working at some point in the past. After a few months I got back and tried to run one of the scripts. The script failed with the following error while it was executing a **ClickCell** operation on a grid object.

```
An error occurred.          
Possible reasons:
1. The application stopped responding.
2. The application was compiled incorrectly (see the Open Applications topic in the help system).
3. An error occurred in TestComplete.

Technical information:
379 0x80070057 (The parameter is incorrect.) .

Tested object:
...
```

I executed the same script on another machine with another Test Complete installation and it worked. So I guess it's not the target app that is the problem.
I checked solutions on the web for this issue, but nothing worked. I cleaned up the temp files in all the locations I could find in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8269386/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-the-parameter-is-incorrect). The behavior was the same.
So I guess it might be something related with the Test Complete installation. I tried reinstalling it a few times, but it didn't do the trick.
I then used Dependency Walker (as suggested somewhere on the web) on testcomplete.exe and found that there are some dlls that are missing from the Bin directory of Test Complete. Could they generate this error? If yes, how can I get them? As I said, I already re-installed the app a few times.
[image: missing Test Complete dlls]

Did anyone bump into this while working with Test Complete? Is there any .net temp location that I should clean?

Comment: Are you testing a .NET Windows Forms application? What exactly controls (name, vendor, version) are used in it? Do you have a controls support extension for the corresponding controls enabled in File | Install Extensions...?

Comment: Yes, i'm testing .NET Windows Forms application. And yes, I have support for the controls. When using Object Spy on the object I can identify it and I can see the ClickCell method listed in the available methods list. This script used to work a while back. The thing is I can't identify the events that took place since it last worked. I think I'll try a re-install for .NET. I saw this as a solution today on a forum.

Comment: Make sure that you have the latest version of the tool which is TestComplete 9.30 and that the version of controls used in your application is supported by TestComplete. You can find information on the supported versions of controls in the tool's documentation.

Comment: We eventually found out that there is no support in 8.7 version of TC for the controls that we were using. We should get 9.0 to work with the controls that seem to be Dev Express specific. Thanks a lot for your answers and for the 'latest version' hint.