# recover corrupt file in visual studio 2010

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010

Suddenly My system is shut down when i was working in visual studio. then again i try to open the file, it was showing some errors..

Then i delete the file on that path and store a backup file..

I am using **asp.net mvc 2**. in my view on that model it is showing an error like following,

```
Asp.net runtime error: Could not load file or assembly 'SFA, Version=1.0.2942.35685, Culture=neutral, PublicKey Token=nu;;' or one of its dependencies. The parameter is in correct.(Exception from HRESULT:0*80070057(E_INVALIDARG))
```

Please give some advice to recover...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Could not load file or assembly ... The parameter is incorrect](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8269386/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-the-parameter-is-incorrect)

Comment: Also, have you tried turning it off and on again, i.e. restart Visual Studio, clean, rebuild? Have you considered using source control?

Comment: I Just build my solution && what is clean solution? what happen if i do this?

Comment: I solved the issue. i just removed the temporary files in my system. now it is working....