# .net: How to clean up corrupted assembly being referenced?

Tags: windows, visual-studio, iis-express

I shut down computer without closing running programs. Now when I run my application on localhost, I'm getting the following error:

```
Could not load file or assembly 'FluentValidation' or one of its dependencies. 
The parameter is incorrect. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070057 (E_INVALIDARG))
```

I've find [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8269386/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-the-parameter-is-incorrect), which explains that I need to cleanup the temporary folder.

I'd like to know what the meaning of cleanup in this case: Just select files in the folder and delete them? I don't want to mess up with my computer.

Thanks for helping.

## EDIT

```
=== Pre-bind state information ===
LOG: DisplayName = FluentValidation
(Partial)
WRN: Partial binding information was supplied for an assembly:
WRN: Assembly Name: FluentValidation | Domain ID: 3
WRN: A partial bind occurs when only part of the assembly display name is   provided.
WRN: This might result in the binder loading an incorrect assembly.
WRN: It is recommended to provide a fully specified textual identity for the assembly,
WRN: that consists of the simple name, version, culture, and public key token.
WRN: See whitepaper http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=109270 for 
more    information 
and common solutions to this issue.
LOG: Appbase = file:///C:/_/trunk/xCIv3.1.0/
LOG: Initial PrivatePath = C:\_\trunk\xCIv3.1.0\bin
Calling assembly : (Unknown).
===
LOG: This bind starts in default load context.
LOG: Using application configuration file: C:\_\trunk\xCIv3.1.0\web.config
LOG: Using host configuration file: 
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet.config
LOG: Using machine configuration file from
   C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
LOG: Policy not being applied to reference at this time (private, custom, partial, 
or location-based assembly bind).
LOG: Attempting download of new URL 
file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework64/v4.0.30319/Temporary ASP.NET
Files/root/ce84b183/bda9c1be/FluentValidation.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL 
file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework64/v4.0.30319/Temporary ASP.NET
Files/root/ce84b183/bda9c1be/FluentValidation/FluentValidation.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL
file:///C:/_/trunk/xCIv3.1.0/bin/FluentValidation.DLL.
LOG: Using application configuration file: C:\_\trunk\xCIv3.1.0\web.config
LOG: Using host configuration file:
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet.config
LOG: Using machine configuration file from 
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
LOG: Policy not being applied to reference at this time (private, custom,
partial, or location-based assembly bind).
ERR: Failed to complete setup of assembly (hr = 0x80070057). Probing terminated.
```

Comment: These files are like an assembly build "cache". You can safely delete all files in, for example, C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\ folder. They will be recreated on the next build.

Comment: Just to confirm what you are saying. Everything that comes after Temporary ASP.NET Files\  can be safely deleted.

Comment: Yes, you probably should leave the temp root folder -->\Temporary ASP.NET Files\

Comment: Why leave that one. Any particular reason?

Comment: It was there after the .NET installation (empty). I am sure that msbuild will not crash if the temp folder has been removed and it would be recreated, however, you have to stop deleting somewhere.

Comment: I've deleted those files and built the solution, but those files have not been recreated.

Comment: So your problem has been solved?

Comment: No. I've deleted the entire content inside the following folder `C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files` and `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files`. I've left root folder but emptied its content. When I build, none of the deleted files are being recreated and I'm still getting the same error: `Could not load file or assembly 'FluentDateTime' ...`

Comment: Don't worry about the contents not being recreated. It does its own thing and puts files there when needed. Nothing is being created there because you haven't had a successful build. At least you ruled out this being a temp folder issue.

Comment: Have you tried deleteing the files in the project\<Debug||Release>\bin?

Comment: Also, what library is FluentDateTime.dll from? You might want to remove that library/package from your project and then add it again from Nuget. To make sure you have the correct version for the framework and that you are not mixing and matching package files.

Comment: I've removed/re-added reference to `FluentDateTime.dll` through Nuget, still without any success. I'll try now deleting  `project\<Debug||Release>\bin`. In addition to `Debug` and `Release` folders, I've also `x64 folder`, which itself contains `Debug` and `Release` folders. Should I delete the `x64 folder` as well?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84386/discussion-between-richard77-and-lrb).