# Could not load file or assembly 'AjaxControlToolkit' or one of its dependencies. The parameter is incorrect

Tags: c#, .net, .net-assembly

My system was shut down unfortunately after restart my system when I am trying to open project in Visual studio 2013, Project build successfully but when open project in browser, I got below error, I tried clear temp memory but I am not able to solved.

Can some one help me please.

Error Message :
Could not load file or assembly 'AjaxControlToolkit' or one of its dependencies. The parameter is incorrect. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070057 (E_INVALIDARG))

Answer (score 0):

Found the same question [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8269386/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-the-parameter-is-incorrect).

Looks like a corrupted assembly being referenced.

Clear both:

1. the \bin folder of your project
2. the temp folder (should be C:\Users\your_username\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files in windows 7)

and see if the error still happens

Answer (score -1):

can you please clear the solutions and then deleted the Ajax control toolkit reference form project then add it again as new one.

or else remove all temporary files from following path
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files