# Error: Could not load file or assembly 'HTML5FileUploadDemo

Tags: c#, .net

I'm trying to build, but I get the following error:

> Could not load file or assembly 'HTML5FileUploadDemo, Version =
>   1.0.0.0, Culture = neutral, PublicKeyToken = null' or one of its dependencies. The parameter is incorrect. (Exception from HRESULT:
>   0x80070057 (E_INVALIDARG))

Any help?
Visual studio 2013

Comment: Did you try http://stackoverflow.com/a/8269493/5296568 ? What kind of library is this? Did you copy all of its dependencies to your application directory?

Comment: Thank you very much, the link helped me. I had to delete unnecessary files