# Could not load file or assembly 'EntityFramework.SqlServer' or one of its dependencies. The parameter is incorrect

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, sql-server-2012, .net-assembly

The following error occurs when I run my project after updating Entity Framework:

> "Could not load file or assembly 'EntityFramework.SqlServer' or one of
>   its dependencies. The parameter is incorrect. (Exception from HRESULT:
>   0x80070057 (E_INVALIDARG))"

Please Give me solution as early as possible thank you!

Comment: remove the temp files from your system and clean and rebuild your solution file. the check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Empty/Delete the 'bin' folder of your start-up project!

Clear the Temp ASP.Net files/assemblies!
See this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8269493/309358)

Generally, the location should be, the below folder.
If you are using other version of framework, then please refer to the SO link I mentioned to find details for cleaning the temp folders for various version of framework.

C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v4.0.30319/Temporary ASP.NET Files

Comment: Do a Solution clean/Rebuild solution!

Comment: Did you try deleting the bin & obj folders of your startup project?

Comment: Yes i do  that dude