# HRESULT 0x80070057 on web server - asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, ajax, iis

We have a web site (.net 3.5) hosted on IIS, its been working fine for a long time. Now suddenly we are getting the following error when user try to access the main site.

```
Exception information: 
Exception type: HttpException 
Exception message: Could not load file or assembly 'AjaxControlToolkit, Version=3.5.40412.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=28f01b0e84b6d53e' or one of its dependencies. The parameter is incorrect. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070057 (E_INVALIDARG)) 

Stack trace:    at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.ReportTopLevelCompilationException()
at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.EnsureTopLevelFilesCompiled()
at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CallAppInitializeMethod()
at System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.Initialize(ApplicationManager appManager, IApplicationHost appHost, IConfigMapPathFactory configMapPathFactory, HostingEnvironmentParameters hostingParameters)
```

No changes has been pushed to web server.

I have done some research on this but people are talking about deleting asp.net temp files from the local machine but this issue is on the windows web server.

Comment: Someone has definitely pushed a changed to the server either the app compilation or the server has been upgraded IIS wise. Check AjaxControlToolkit.dll  is in your bin.

Comment: yes AjaxControlToolkit.dll is there in the bin. I have checked the last updated data in the web directory and i don't see anything new in there.

Comment: Is this a dedicate server you own or provided by someone else, as in shared hosting?

Comment: Its a dedicated server we own.

Comment: Give this a try: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8269386/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-the-parameter-is-incorrect

Comment: is it safe to delete temp files from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files?

Comment: Take a backup, but anything in Temporary should be fine.

Comment: This worked for me; Create a new application pool

Go to the Advanced Settings of this application pool

Set the Enable 32-Bit Application to True

Point your web application to use this new pool

Comment: i still don't understand why is it working now?

Comment: Windows being windows.... Glad it's working for you. Nothing worse than a suddenly not working app.

Comment: I managed to fix this issue by deleting one Temporary ASP.NET Files folder, i had to enable Fusion to find the folder which was being accessed by main website. Thanks for the link.